# Run commands in codeship without vm for every commit in a branch

Tags: github, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, codeship

I want to deploy my application in github page. I want the build job to be automated. My build commands basically include running unit tests,building a production version, gh-deploy command to deploy to github page. Can i achieve this using code ship. Do i require a actual vm like ec2 to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The official automation process with [codeship](https://documentation.codeship.com/) involves [pushing to GitHub](https://documentation.codeship.com/basic/continuous-deployment/push-to-remote-repository/).
If your build process can populate the content you want to publish, then you can simply push it from the codeship job itself.

As an example, see "[Auto-deploying to `gh-pages` with Codeship](https://www.drinkingcaffeine.com/auto-deploying-to-gh-pages-with-codeship/) " (Martyn Chamberlin), which is about publishing a Gulp build:

```sh
git  clone <the ssh link to your repo> dist
cd dist
git checkout gh-pages || git checkout --orphan gh-pages
cd ..
rm -rf dist/**/* || exit 0
npm install
gulp deploy
cd dist
git config user.email "<the email address you used for your machine user GitHub account>"
git config user.name "<the username you used for your machine user GitHub account>"
git add .
git commit -m "Deploy to GitHub Pages: ${CI_COMMIT_ID} --skip-ci"
git push origin gh-pages
```

> This is a clever little set of commands, really.
>   It’s creating a git repo inside of another git repo in order to handle the build correctly.
>   I wish I could say I was the one who came up with this idea but the hat tip belongs to [Domenic](https://github.com/domenic) who gave me the idea with his Travis gist.
>
> A few things to note about this:
>
> - This assumes that `npm install; gulp deploy` is the series of commands you use to combine and minify your assets.
>     That’s true of my project but yours may be different (particularly the second one). Be sure to replace lines 6 and 7 with your actual ones (as well as the  values, of course).
> - This also assumes your output directory is `dist`. Hopefully it is, because that’s the convention, but if you’ve got something else, you’ll need to update lines 1, 2, and 8.
> - I’m completely bypassing Codeship’s recommendation of handling the final git push via their own provided code (“include the commands from [`continuous-deployments/git-push.sh`](https://codeship.com/documentation/continuous-deployment/push-to-remote-repository/)”).
>     Not a big deal either way, I just don’t see the need for an extra HTTP request.